# Matlab script not found from django views.py

Tags: python, django, matlab, python-2.7, pydev

I have a user-made Matlab script in the same directory as my views.py page, but when it is called I receive the error: `Undefined function 'getRecs' for input arguments of type 'double'.` Basically the script wasn't found.

When I test the script with a test.py script in the same directory everything works fine, but when called through the views.py via my browser and the development server the error appears.

**tools.py:**

```
def get_recs(passed_list):
   eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
   recs = eng.getRecs(passed_list)
   return recs
```

**test.py:** (works fine and is in same directory as views.py and getRecs.m)
(Ran using Pydev's run as: Python run)

```
from tools import *

test_ratings = [5, 0, 3, 2, 1, 5]
conv_rates = matlab.double(initializer=test_ratings)
new_recs = get_recs(conv_rates)
print_list(new_recs)
```

**views.py:** (throws error)

```
from tool import *
test_ratings = [5, 0, 3, 2, 1, 5]
def new_user(request):
    conv_rates = matlab.double(initializer=test_ratings)
    new_recs = get_recs(conv_rates)
    return render_to_response('new_user.html', { 'ratings_list' :new_recs}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm using Python 2.7, Django 1.9, and Matlab R2015b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone having this problem in the future: like Selcuk mentioned the development server defines its own directory so you need to add the path to the scripts you want to use to the engine. I did this by addding

```
eng.addpath(r'C:\path\to\my\scripts\')
```

after initializing and starting the engine.

Comment: Calling `eng.savepath()` might work to set it up only once.

Answer (score 1):

Django development server (or WSGI server) defines a different default directory than the one your user script resides. Try adding the location of your user script to the search path using `addpath` option:

```
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab("-addpath /var/django/myproject/myapp/")
```

Comment: Although the line of code you provided did not solve the problem, thank you for explaining that the WSGI server defines a different directory and pointing me in the right direction, much appreciated